# MongoDB data corruption on a replica set

Tags: mongodb, corruption, recovery, replicaset

I am working with a MongoDB database running in a replica set.

Unfortunately, I noticed that the data appears to be corrupted.

There should be over 10,000 documents in the database. However, there are several thousand records that are not being returned in queries.

The total count DOES show the correct total.

```
db.records.find().count()
10793
```

And some records are returned when querying by RecordID (a custom sequence integer).

```
db.records.find({"RecordID": 10049})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dfbdb35c1c2a400104edece")
```

However, when querying for a records that I know for a fact should exist, it does not return anything.

```
db.records.find({"RecordID": 10048})
db.records.find({"RecordID": 10047})
db.records.find({"RecordID": 10046})
```

The issue appears to be very sporadic, and in some cases entire ranges of records are missing. The entire range from RecordIDs 1500 to 8000 is missing.

Questions: What could be the cause of the issue? What can I do to troubleshoot this issue further and recover the corrupted data? I looked into running repairDatabase but that is for standalone instances only.

UPDATE:

More info on replication:

```
rs.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size:   5100.880859375MB
log length start to end: 14641107secs (4066.97hrs)
oplog first event time:  Wed Mar 03 2021 05:21:25 GMT-0500 (EST)
oplog last event time:   Thu Aug 19 2021 17:19:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)
now:                     Thu Aug 19 2021 17:20:01 GMT-0400 (EDT)

rs.printSecondaryReplicationInfo()
source: node2-examplehost.com:27017
        syncedTo: Thu Aug 19 2021 17:16:42 GMT-0400 (EDT)
        0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
source: node3-examplehost.com:27017
        syncedTo: Thu Aug 19 2021 17:16:42 GMT-0400 (EDT)
        0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

UPDATE 2:
We did a restore from a backup and somehow it looks like it fixed the issue.

Comment: From the [count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/) documentation: *Avoid using count() if the find() operation is run without a query predicate since without the query predicate, these count() returns results based on the collection's metadata, which may result in an approximate count.*

Comment: What is the replica set status (`rs.status` and `rs.printReplicationInfo()`) Do you connect to PRIMARY or SECONDARY? What is your read preference?

Comment: A repair of a replicat set is usually: Stop the secondary mongod - delete all files from `dbPath` folder - start mongod process again. After start it will perform an [inital sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#initial-sync)

Comment: Thanks! In this case it looks like the count() with and without find is returning the same result. db.records.find().count()
10793
db.records.count()
10793
Looking into answers to your other questions now. Thanks again

Comment: Sequence generators are generally frowned upon when using MongoDB.  If not done properly, it can lead to race conditions where two inserts try to use the same sequence generated value, but only one succeeds, the other fails.  If your application swallows these errors you will have missing data.  I would encourage you to evaluate if your application can experience this condition and if so, what is your resolution strategy.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've updated the post description with the outputs of the printReplicationInfo and printSecondaryReplicationInfo commands with the hostnames obfuscated. Anything else I can do for troubleshooting purposes?

Comment: Also, if you are querying (reading from) a secondary, but comparing to inserts on a primary, replication lag could appear as if data is missing.  Secondaries are eventually consistent.

Comment: @barrypicker hm I see what you mean the count() returns the correct number of documents, but only a small percentage of them are returning in queries. So it seems unlikely that there would be simultaneous inserts causing this issue. Also this application is only used by a small group of users so it would be unlikely for this to become such a widespread issue so suddenly. Also, there are thousands of documents that were definitely present before that are no longer showing up in queries.

Comment: @barrypicker I see what you mean but it looks a lot more like a corruption issue or perhaps inconsistency between replicas. There are thousands of documents that were definitely returning in queries before, but are no longer returning.

Comment: Can you show what the results of this query are: `db.records.find({}).sort({"RecordID": -1}).limit(1)`. - at least show what the value is of field "RecordID" anyways - don't need the entire document.

Comment: @barrypicker db.records.find({}).sort({"RecordID": -1}).limit(1)
{ "RecordID" : 10050 }

Comment: So, if you have 10793 records, but the largest is 10050 you must have some duplicates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236215/discussion-between-barrypicker-and-pengz).

Answer (score 0):

We did a restore from a backup and somehow it looks like it fixed the issue.